# How to prevent logs on Console ( STDOUT) for TypeSafe Activator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, typesafe-activator

I am using TypeSafe Activator on Windows 7 for running Spark Scala. The problem is every time I run a program it prints lots of verbose logs on the console (STDOUT), I don’t want to see them because my specific messages are getting lost in the clutter. 
Any idea how the verbose logs can be turned off, or even better if I can have my messages on a different console.

I also keeep getting the following error every time I make an code changes and try to run

> registered more than once? Task((taskDefinitionKey:
>   ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/C:/Users/E498164/Documents/Hadoop/SparkProject/hello-apache-spark/,hello-apache-spark)),Select(ConfigKey(compile)),Select(run),Global),runner)))
>   Use 'last' for the full log.